# What is the most efficient way to convert from a list of values to a scipy sparse matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a list of values that I'm using a loop to convert to a [`scipy.sparse.dok_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html). I'm aware of [`numpy.bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) but it doesn't work with sparse matrices. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to perform this conversion because the construction time for a `dok_matrix` is really long.

Example below for one row but I'm scaling to a 2D matrix by looping. The number of times a value `x` appears in the input list is the value of the `x`th element of the result matrix.

```py
values = [1, 3, 3, 4]
expected_result = [0, 1, 0, 2, 1]

matrix = dok_matrix((1, MAXIMUM_EXPECTED_VALUE))
for value in values:
    matrix[0, value] = matrix.get((0, card)) + 1
```

`MAXIMUM_EXPECTED_VALUE` is in the order of 100000000 but `len(values) < 100`, which is why I'm using a sparse matrix. Possibly off-topic: there are also only a little over 10000 actual values that are used in the range of `MAXIMUM_EXPECTED_VALUE` but I think hashing to a contiguous range and converting back might be more complicated.

Comment: Why can't you just make an array that has the column indices and an array that has the values and use a standard constructor? Also dok type sparse matrices are basically useless.

Comment: Are you referring to a standard numpy array? And yes, I do have to convert from dok to csr for the actual application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the standard `coo` style inputs suits you case:

```
In [143]: from scipy import sparse
In [144]: values = [1,3,3,4]
In [145]: col = np.array(values)
In [146]: row = np.zeros_like(col)
In [147]: data = np.ones_like(col)
In [148]: M = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row,col)), shape=(1,10))
In [149]: M
Out[149]: 
<1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [150]: M.A
Out[150]: array([[0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Does this scale to an entire 2D matrix with more than one row? (e.g. instead of `matrix[0, value]` in my example, I'm looping from 0 to the number of rows)

Comment: Sure, the `row` array can be made with `arange`.  In more complex cases these arrays are built with list append/extend or concatenating a list of arrays.

Comment: Would that be most efficient compared to vstacking single-row coo matrices?

Comment: `sparse.vstack` starts with `coo` of all inputs, and combines their attributes to make the `coo` inputs of the new matrirx.  It uses `sparse.bmat`